# Beamer: Line spacing in title

Tags: beamer, titles, line-spacing

I have a long title for my beamer presentation and ue the `\titlepage{}` command. The title is automatically split over 4 lines. As I am using a tall font (arev), these lines are squashed together. I can use something like `\newline \vskipt6pt` where the line breaks occur to get roughly what I want (using `\\` seems to insert a spurious comma). I am using the contributed Torino theme.
This there a way to `automatically' increase this spacing for the title only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\fontsize` to control the font size (first argument) and the value of `\baselineskip` (second argument); usually, the value for the second argument is aprox. 20% more than the first argument, but you can use the value that best suits your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Torino}
\usepackage{arev}

\author{T.H.E. Author}
\title{\fontsize{28}{35}\selectfont A really really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  long long title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer - changing the first parameter does change the font size, however, changing the second parameter does not appear to affect the output, even for the simple example you made. Any idea why not?

Comment: @prettygully: before posting the answer I did several tests in which I verified that changing the second argument would in fact modify `\baselineskip`. If you are getting something different, please add a minimal version of the problematic code to your question.

Comment: This happened for your nice example. As it worked for you, I suspected that it might be my Torino files & downloaded them again. No idea why, but now all works as it should - thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can edit the innertheme file and add something like

```
\setlength\lineskip{6pt}
```

right before the `\inserttitle` command.

If you want to use Torino with the `alternativetitlepage` option, you have to go this way, because there is a `\offinterlineskip` command that overrides what you set.

Comment: thanks very much; I'll try that for my next presentation.

Answer (score 5):

about the spurious comma when using `\\` in the title with the torino theme, there is a command redefinition in the template file `beamerinnerthemefancy.sty` line 81:

```
\def\\{,}\vbox{}\vskip-1.5ex
```

which redefines `\\` as a colon and some space. If you change the line 81 from

```
  \@tempdima=\textwidth\textwidth=\paperwidth\hsize=\textwidth\def\\{,}\vbox{}\vskip-1.5ex%
```

to

```
  \@tempdima=\textwidth\textwidth=\paperwidth\hsize=\textwidth%\def\\{,}\vbox{}\vskip-1.5ex
```

you can use `\\` in the title again

Answer (score 2):

I used `\newline` to control the breaks where I wanted them to occur:

```
\title{A really really  really  \newline
really  really  really  really  \newline
really  really  really  really  \newline
long long title}
```

Comment: As the title is sometimes also displayed in the footline, this can cause some problems, better use `\title[A short version]{A really really  really  \newline
really  really  really  really  \newline
really  really  really  really  \newline
long long title}`