# Distance between multiple lines in header of beamer template

Tags: beamer, header-footer, line-spacing

this is my first question ;). I have defined a custom header in my beamer template and I want to show multiple lines. Since \\ isn't available in beamercolorbox I had to use \newline instead. The problem is that I cannot define a distance between the lines! I cannot use \vspace or another \newline.

Any idea?

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: If you are willing to manually justify the header content, then the `stackengine` package allows syntax such as `\stackunder[spacing]{top line}{bottom line}`.

Comment: does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21671/beamer-line-spacing-in-title help?

Comment: I don't know why this question has been closed, it seems relevant to me. I found a solution using first \vspace[0.2cm] on my first line, then \newline.