# Line spacing in title of Beamer poster

Tags: beamer, titles, line-spacing, beamerposter

I am trying to make the line spacing bigger in the title of a Beamer poster but the second argument of `fontsize` is not working. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21671/beamer-line-spacing-in-title) seems to be the same as mine (although not for Beamer poster), but the solution provided there is not working in my case, I don't know why.

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait]{beamerposter}

\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=white,bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
    \leavevmode
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
        \begin{columns}[T]
            \begin{column}{.5\paperwidth}
                \vskip4ex
                \begin{center}
                    \vskip 2.75ex
                    % Changing the 2nd argument of fontsize does not change anything
                    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\fontsize{60}{10} \selectfont \inserttitle}}
                    \vskip 2.75ex
                \end{center}
                \vskip4ex
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\title{A long title of a paper whose interline spacing I want to increase}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

1. to end the current paragraph before switching back to a smaller font
2. the second argument with the baseline skip should normally be bigger than the font size

I'd also avoid adding spaces manually and adjust the `sep` of the `beamercolorbox` instead:

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait]{beamerposter}

\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=white,bg=gray}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,size*={60}{72}}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \leavevmode
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,sep=8ex,center]{headline}
        \begin{minipage}{.5\paperwidth}
                \centering
                \usebeamerfont{title}%
                \inserttitle\par
        \end{minipage}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\title{A long title of a paper whose interline spacing I want to increase}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]